# Need to handle the spaces between the filename in Control-M File watcher command

Tags: control-m

I have File watcher job which is looking for certain file name(Membership Daily 20191230.xslx). Could some one share some insights how to handle the space between the file when i provided the path with file name?

Usually will use * as wild card search  but i have the different files which are closer with member.

**Server File Watcher Run :** UNIX

[image]

Comment: Encase the full file path in quotation marks.

Comment: is it the single quote or double quotes ??

Comment: @JooBear can you please confirm which one of the pattren is right ?
'/data/member/input/membership daily 20191230.xslx'
or 
"/data/member/input/membership daily 20191230.xslx"
or
`/data/member/input/membership daily 20191230.xslx`

Comment: Single or double will work. As long as you stick with the same on both ends. Quote type matters more when executing more complex command lines.

Answer (score 2):

Enclose the full path name in quotation marks (for example, “c:\ctm\My Example.txt”). Only if a file name is in a Rules file containing a wildcard, *then* the filename should not be enclosed in quotation marks.

If you don't want to use spaces, one **?** will wildcard for any one character, for example c:\ctm\My?File?Example.txt.

Comment: if i have the wild card pattern enable and the file contains the wild card search , in this case would double quotes work ?
For instance when i keep the Wild card option - Yes and the file contains this pattern “c:\ctm\My Example*.txt” ?does doubleor single quotes work ?

Comment: the below format worked for me 

Invalid: "test/input/touch file*.txt"

Valid: test/mahi/"touch file*.txt"

Comment: Is this just your opinion? I’ve never read anything about not using quotation marks only when using wildcards?